# Method contains another method

Tags: c#-3.0

Can we use a method within an another method in C#

Comment: Please give more details - what do you mean by "use" here? You can obviously *call* one method from another... What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

No that is not possible. The closest *nested-like method* is probably an [anonymous method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k(VS.80).aspx).
Example from msdn:

```
void StartThread()
{
    System.Threading.Thread t1 = new System.Threading.Thread
      (delegate()
            {
                System.Console.Write("Hello, ");
                System.Console.WriteLine("World!");
            });
    t1.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an anonymous delegate if you want a function with the lexical scope of your method.